# Apple USB keyboard(s) have some keys that don't work, tried everything

Tags: usb, keyboard, macbook-pro, macos-highsierra

Thanks for taking the time to help me out on this. Fist I think it is important to know that I am more than an average user, so I think this is my last resort before doing a complete wipe of my computer (macOS High Sierra 10.13.5, MBPRO 2,7Ghz Intel Core i7).

I am faced with a bit of a conundrum here... when I connect an external USB keyboard certain keys won't execute. These are the v, f, keypad-0 and backspace. I cannot get them to work... please look through this list of the things I tried:

- tried 3 different apple keyboards and 1 hp keyboard on different usb hubs on the laptop and powered usb-hub, so the same keys don't work on the different keyboards.
- updated to newest OS
- resetted SMC
- resetted PRAM
- tried remapping keys with Karabiner (also no recognition on key-down)
- tried direct usb connect
- tried powered usb via usb hub
- disconnect everything except the keyboard (also with restart)
- rumours that usb extension cable could work did nothing
- removed global preferences file (terminal: defaults delete -g)
- New admin user has same problems (Thanks Tetsujin)
- I made a bootable USB High Sierra USB and booted from it. And even there the issue persists. So I recon this is hardware somehow, strange as is sounds.

I am out of ideas.

Comment: 'tried more than 1 keyboard' ... same or different types, Mac or PC keyboards? Also, it's not totally clear if you tried different USB ports on the Mac itself.

Comment: So every other keyboard you have tried the same keys don't work?

Comment: Grab a USB HDD - Run setup from your setup partition and install another system to the USB HDD. This simulates a rebuild without deleting your system.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas That is correct... same issue on different keyboards. And yeah, before i'll cleaninstall ill boot from usb-hdd. I'm hoping that somebody had this issue and have en more.... 'effective' fix. Can't afford downtime atm. Thanks.

Comment: Expanding on @JohnnyVegas 's comment. You could try setting up a new admin account & test on that; try re-installing the OS from Recovery Cmd/R, which won't change anything other than overlay a clean OS.

Comment: @Tetsujin new admin user.... great tip. will try that right now.

Comment: @Tetsujin good idea but unfortunately it dit not work

Comment: OK, I'd think next best chance of success would be new OS on new drive, 2nd best, Recovery. If one works & the other doesn't you're gonna have to start digging deeper for the conflict.

Comment: Hmmm should I move this post to https://apple.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: It's fine on either.... but not both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78775/discussion-between-kortschot-and-tetsujin).

Comment: I made a bootable USB High Sierra USB and booted from it. And even there the issue persists. So I recon this is hardware somehow, strange as is sounds.

Comment: AHT then, I guess

Comment: Have you tried a bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: Yeah, later today I'll do a AHT on the road now. Did not tried a BT since I don't have one (a wire doesn't bother me as much as having no batteries).

Will update when I have something new.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Well AHT showed nothing... so a total clean install did the trick. Thanks for the help.